# Custom font for chapter titles not working

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I use the `titlesec` package to custom my chapter titles. I want to use a font from the `librebodoni` package that is [already installed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416633/manually-installing-font-tex-package) (the commande `\usepackage{LibreBodoni}` works fine but changes the font in the whole document).

I tried `\fontfamily{librebodonifamily}\selectfont` as this seems to be the name of the font family defined in `librebodoni.sty`, but it did not work and returned the following message:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/librebodonifamily/bx/n' undefined
>   (Font)              using`T1/librebodonifamily/m/n' instead on input
>   line 1.
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/librebodonifamily/bx/it' undefined
>   (Font)              using`T1/librebodonifamily/bx/n' instead on input
>   line 1.

I tried other reasonable family names but none is working... Does anyone have a clue how to solve this problem? Thanks by advance.

I use `pdflatex`.

Comment: `librebodonifamily` is not the right name. Can you please add a minimal example of code?

Comment: The right  name of the family for `pdflatex` seems to be `LibreBodoni-TLF` (there are two other families for superior and inferior figures, but most likely you won't need them in section titles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a new command to switch to the font. In this example, `\librebodoni` switches to the font, while `\textlb{<text>}` typesets `<text>` in the font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% you seem to be using this encoding
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\librebodoni{\not@math@alphabet\librebodoni\relax\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{LibreBodoni-TLF}\selectfont}
\makeatother
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textlb{\librebodoni}
\begin{document}
Some text in ordinary serif.

\textlb{A short text in Libre Bodoni}

Back to default.

{\librebodoni
  A longer text with more than one paragraph.

  This is the other one.%
}

Back to default.
\end{document}
```

[image: switching to Libre Bodoni]

Note that, depending on your default document font, you may not wish to use the bold. In comparison with Computer Modern, for example, the regular weight of Libre Bodoni already looks bold, and the bold is really extremely shouty. Of course, if your default fonts are heavier, this may not be the case.

[image: shoutier bold]